# Complexidade do algoritmo strand sort

Tags: lista, algoritmo, desempenho, classificação, complexidade-de-algoritmo

Estou utilizando o **strand sort** para fazer um trabalho da faculdade e queria saber se em nível de complexidade, em pior caso ele O(n^2). e eu queria saber em qual circunstancia seria melhor utilizar essa ordenação e por que ?

Comment: Esse algoritmo é melhor utilizado em linked lists, pois como o algoritmo produz muita reamostragem se aplicado em vetores a complexidade de tempo aumenta por conta das inserções. O pior caso(complexidade de tempo) ocorre quando aplicado em vetores ordenados decrescentemente.